# How change the base path use by the routing system in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

I'm new in Laravel and I start to set my routes. I use laravel 5.1 on a local wamp server.

I'm on local, http://localhost/ttt/ goes on `/public` directory of Laravel.

When I try this :

```
Route::get('admin',function(){
    echo 4;
});
```

and go to http://localhost/ttt/admin, I got an error but when I do this :

```
Route::get('ttt/admin',function(){
    echo 4;
});
```

It work.
I check the config and changed the `url` value in `config/app.php` but it doesn't work.

Do you know if there is a kind of path used by the router that I can config?

Comment: That's the correct way to do it. What was the error you got?

Comment: I got an error telle me the route don't exist, when you say the correct way, you talking about the second snippet ?

Comment: Have you correctly configured your http server to serve your application from a subdirectory? If you haven't, you can do the following for [Apache](http://mackhankins.com/blog/laravel-5-virtual-host-for-an-apache-subdirectory) or [nginx](https://gist.github.com/tsolar/8d45ed05bcff8eb75404).

Comment: Can you copy and paste the __exact__ error into your question please along with any HTTP status codes such as 500 or 404 etc.

Comment: @BenSwinburne the message just say the route doesn't exit : "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.", "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161"

Comment: Are you **positive** that the public root is set to the `ttt` folder? Because it seems like the public root (where `index.php` lives and all requests are sent through) is actually at http://localhost, based on the fact that your `ttt/admin` route is working.

Answer (score 2):

You could `prefix` each route in the initial route group,

**App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider@map**:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'ttt', 'namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
    require app_path('Http/routes.php');
});
```

Comment: Ok, i thought about it but when I do redirect()->guest('auth/login'); it lead me to http://localhost/auth/login instead of http://localhost/ttt/auth/login, this is why i want to define a king of global path. is it possible than Laravel can't be install on a subdirectory without core fil modification ?